# Python -- Share a Numpy Array Between Processes?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to use `python's` `multiprocessing` module to utilize a multi-core Linux server.

I need all processes to have read/write access to the same shared memory.

Instead of using a `list` or a `queue`, is it possible to have a multi-dimentional `numpy` array as the shared object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.ruxizhang.com/uploads/4/4/0/2/44023465/multiprocessing-tutorial.pdf). I doesn't seem easy, but it's doable.

Edit: Link rotted, I have linked to another copy.

Comment: Link has rotted away.

Answer (score 9):

I think I know what you're looking for: https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem/issue/3/casting-complex-ndarray-to-float-in

There's a short description on the web page saying: A shared memory module for numpy by Sturla Molden and G. Varoquaux that makes it easy to share memory between processes in the form of NumPy arrays. Originally posted to SciPy-user mailing list.

I, myself am using it just that way. Sharing NumPy arrays between processes. Works very well for me.

Comment: Could you please update the above link? It doesn't lead to the code anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found that even if you do not modify your numpy array after fork()'ing a bunch of child processes, you will still see your RAM skyrocket as childprocesses copy-on-write the object for some reason.

You can limit (or totally alleviate?) this problem by setting

```
"yourArray.flags.writeable = False"
```

BEFORE fork()'ing/Pool()'ing which seems to keep the RAM used down, and is a LOT less hassle than the other methods :)

Comment: the correct syntax is  : `myarray.flags['WRITEABLE'] = False`